# Open my app from facebook app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an application on IOS, which posts photos and location on facebook.

I want my app to open once user tap on link(When viewing facebook from facebook app). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible using the built in iOS sharing but Facebook will open your app if you are using their SDK and posting with a Facebook app. (as in an app setup in their developer portal) You need to have deep linking turned on and your app profile setup to point back to your app store id. They also have a new app links thing they announced which is worth checking out. In any case your app will have to support custom URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can not get clearly but if I am not wrong then do you want to open your iOS app when user click on link on FB  ?

If I am right then simple and sort answer, **it is not possible** because apple iOS dose not provide any such types of feature/API so it is better to stop fighting.

Comment: this should be a comment.